# SF novel with a star system surrounded by a shield/force field; main character is an alien made of several individuals

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

Was lent a book a few years ago.  May have been part 1 of 2 or 3.

Humans identify a star system which is quarantined; surrounded by some sort of shield or force field. Within the shield boron fusion-powered spaceships operate.  The central character from early on in the book is an alien life form which is formed of four (I think) individuals who grow together / combine to form a compound intelligence but lack the ability to move; they have unintelligent drone lifeforms which can move and obey commands.  They're implacably hostile to all other life forms, hence the quarantine; it wasn't to keep others out but to keep this race in.

The compound life form continues to grow by assimilation; can't remember its name but it includes "Mountain".  A human exploratory team is captured and dissected by the drones as "Mountain whatever" tries to work out the nature of the threat.

Comment: see OP comment below confirming duplicate status

Answer (score 8):

This sounds like the [*Commonwealth Series*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonwealth_Saga) by Peter Hamilton. The first book was [*Pandora's Star*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonwealth_Saga#Pandora's_Star). The sequel was [*Judas Unchained*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonwealth_Saga#Judas_Unchained).

The first book is the specific book to which you are referring. Though it sounds like you might be mixing the plot lines of the two books a bit.

In the series the alien called Prime is sealed within the star system to protect other species. It captures the ship *Second Chance* and dissects the exploratory crew sent to discover why the star had suddenly disappeared.

The Prime's name is **MorningLightMountain**.

Comment: Can you offer some specifics why you think this is the right answer...

Comment: The Prime's name is Morning Light Mountain.

Comment: Thank you for your responses to my question. This is indeed the story I was trying to remember.  I'm grateful to you.

Comment: Thanks emmcee. If this is the correct answer if you could please accept the answer that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed the *Commonwealth* series by Peter F. Hamilton.

**The central character from early on in the book is an alien lifeform which is formed of four (I think) individuals who grow together / combine to form a compound intelligence**

> The four largest herd members pressed up against each other, allowing
>   their nerve receptors to touch so that their brains were linked
>   together... joined like this their decision-making capability was
>   significantly enhanced... At the end of the process, the new immotile
>   Prime, MorningLightMountain, began to secure its territory.

These aliens colonize the next solar system. A few years later the two star systems get into a war with each other. A third race, wary of the warlike nature of this species, encloses the two stars in an unbreakable forcefield.

From the human space it looks like two stars suddenly went off. The human spaceship sent to check it inadvertently turns the force fields off allowing the aliens out. Two crew members are left behind and captured by MorningLightMountain which dissects them to study them.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response to my question. This is indeed the story I was trying to remember.  I'm grateful to you.